# Tkinter and ttkbootstrap deprication warning and other errors I dont understand

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkbootstrap

I am a beginner in python and I am learning to use Tkinter with ttkboostrap to create an app for our math subject. after writing a bit of code for the setup it shows an error many errors which I don't understand. Below is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
import ttkbootstrap as tb

root = tb.Window(themename="vapor")

root.title("Ttk Boostrap prac")
root.geometry("500x500")

root.mainloop()
```

** below is the error message**

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gabriele/XU/3rd Year/Math/Ui.py", line 33, in <module>
    root = Window()
  File "/Users/gabriele/XU/3rd Year/Math/Ui.py", line 25, in __init__
    image = Image.open("path/to/your/image.png")
  File "/Users/gabriele/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3243, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path/to/your/image.png'
```

Edit Supra's screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The code given in the question and the error does not seem to match

Comment: it really is what the error message says, that is why I also didn't understand why returns an error message about images when I didn't even use images. Anyways, I got the solution, I just updated my python to the latest version.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue with the posted code.  Note that `root = Window()` is used in the exception traceback, but `root = tb.Window(themename="vapor")` is used in posted code.  So the posted code should not be the code generating the exception.

Comment: It worked for me running under Python 3.12.0rc3.  Updating Python will prevent any errors.